# combine 3 select statment from the same table into 1 table in sql

Tags: sql-server, select, combinations

I  am trying to run 3 different `select query` on 1 table  where i return the count of **created**, **done**, **pending** tasks based on **created_date**  and **modified_date**
where i can differentiate the **done** from **pending** in **modified_date** based on the field **status**

when i run each query separately it return correct answer.

But what i want is to combine these 3 queries in one table as below:

```
+---------------------- +------------------+---------------------+
|  Total_created_files  | Total_done_files | Total_pending_files |
+-----------------------+------------------+---------------------+
|          14           |         40       |         9           | 
+-----------------------+------------------+---------------------+
```

## code:

```
select 
count([create_date]) as Total_created_files
FROM [TEC_APP].[dbo].[case_to_do]
where  [create_date] >='2022-05-01 00:00:00.000'
AND
CAST([create_date] AS date) <=  CAST(GETDATE() AS date)

select 
count([modified_date]) as Total_done_files
FROM [TEC_APP].[dbo].[case_to_do]
where  [modified_date] >='2022-05-01 00:00:00.000'
AND
CAST([modified_date] AS date) <=  CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
AND
status = 'DONE'

select 
count([modified_date]) as Total_pending_files
FROM [TEC_APP].[dbo].[case_to_do]
where  [modified_date] >='2022-05-01 00:00:00.000'
AND
CAST([modified_date] AS date) <=  CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
AND
status = 'Pending'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation to `COUNT` as needed. I make a couple of assumptions here, but this should be what you are after:

```sql
USE TEC_APP;
GO

SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN [create_date] < DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(date,GETDATE())) THEN 1 END) AS Total_created_files,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [modified_date] >= '20220501' AND [modified_date] < DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(date,GETDATE())) AND Status = 'DONE' THEN 1 END) AS Total_done_files,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [modified_date] >= '20220501' AND [modified_date] < DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(date,GETDATE())) AND Status = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) AS Total_pending_files
FROM [dbo].[case_to_do]
WHERE create_date >= '20220501'; --Presumably something can't be modified before it's created.
```

Comment: this was what i want thanks ... what if i want to show grouped by date  like i want to display in `20220501| 6 created_files | 1 done_file | 2 pending_files
 in 20220502| 1created_file | 3 done_files| 3 pending_files`

Comment: Add the date column into your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` presumably, @khaledM_dev .

Comment: that is my question how to get the range of date   if i do not have it as columns .. can i create a variable that handle the hall month and then grouped  by this variable ?

Comment: That isn't what you ask, @khaledM_dev . This sounds like you have a new question, which should be asked as a [New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: yes you are right this is another question thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation with `case expression`:

```
SELECT SUM(case when <First Condition here> then 1 else 0 end) as Total_created_files,
       SUM(case when <Second Condition here> then 1 else 0 end) as Total_done_files,
       SUM(case when <Third Condition here> then 1 else 0 end) as Total_pending_files
FROM [TEC_APP].[dbo].[case_to_do]
```